# Не понимаю как правильно сверстать, а затем позиционировать такие картинки в блоке, как можно лучше сделать? в какую сторону подглядеть можно?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

все пытался через position absolute, но черти что получается, за адаптацией потом месяц сидеть буду, как можно сделать правильней?

Comment: Поделить на две колонки и просто пустить в поток с отступом margin-bottom - для всех, кроме последнего

Comment: Две колонки. `display: flex;`, `align-items: center;`, а иконку инстаграмма `position: absolute`

Comment: Спасибо большое, пока ответа ждал, бошка сама до этого додумалась, не совсем так, но благодаря вам подправил